# Why redis.conf is become a directory after Redis docker container created

Tags: docker, redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I'm trying to create Redis cluster and one of its container with command:

```
docker run -d -v cluster-config.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name redis-1 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

The same way I create another `redis-2`,...,`redis-6` containers.

My `cluster-config.conf` contains:

> port 6379
>      cluster-enabled yes
>      cluster-config-file nodes.conf
>      cluster-node-timeout 5000
>      appendonly yes

But when I exec into any of this container I found `/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` isn't a file, it becomes a folder:

```
# cat redis.conf
cat: redis.conf: Is a directory
```

What i did wrong so redis.conf became a directory?

Comment: Since `cluster-config.conf` isn't an absolute path, Docker interprets it as a volume name; it creates a new empty Docker volume and mounts the directory tree on that path.  Try `-v $(pwd)/cluster-config.conf:...` instead to force it to be an absolute path.

Comment: For my Windows workstation this one is worked `... -v $PWD/cluster-config.conf:...` Thanks, @DavidMaze.